# Round a float to -1, 0 or 1

Tags: c#, rounding

I need to round a float to -1 or 1. If the float equals 0 then leave it at zero.
Right now I use this:

```
Mathf.Clamp(x*1000000, -1f,1)
```

is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Elegance is subjective.  What is wrong with your method (assuming it works)?

Comment: So if the float is (say) 3 it should round to 1? And is it is 4, it should also round to 1? What about -3.5 and -10000?

Comment: @GottZ Having just read the documentation, I can confirm that I should have googled before I typed ;) Thanks

Comment: if the number -4.7 should we round to -1 or -5 ?

Comment: How about: if x is zero, return 0. Otherwise, check the sign of x - if it is negative return -1, otherwise return 1.

Comment: or if greater than zero, if less etc.

Comment: well it cannot get more elegant than using a clamp function. after all thats what its there for. yes you could write: `x > 1 ? 1 : x < -1 : -1 : x` or the min max example i wrote but seriously.. using clamp is much more elegant

Comment: oh ye you are right @Chris 1 and -1 have to be swapped in my example. since i cannot edit it cause its to old: `min(max(x, -1), 1)`

Comment: there. i edited my examples. now they are correct.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. Can you clarify if x is 0.000000001 (and thus x*1000000 is 0.001) do you want to return 1 or 0.001?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Math.Sign(x)` to do this. It will return 0 when x=0, -1 if x is negative and +1 if x is positive. I believe this does what you want. Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z394hhsx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: na that will only return -1, 1 and 0. please don't confuse it with my old example in his comment. clamping means to only allow a certain range. everything beyond is fixed to the ranges min / max

Comment: @GottZ: That is what I assume the OP wants. I assume that the multiply by 1000000 is to make sure that the clamped number is outside of the (1,-1) range and thus only returns 1, 0 or -1. If that's not what the multiply is for then I am not sure what it is in the question for... (Clarification requested in comment on the question)

Comment: @Chris: Yes, I used the multiplication to make sure x is outside of the (1,-1) range. I totaly forgot about Sign() method. that is spot on what I need. Thanks.